# Combine two xml files using a new node

Tags: c#

This how my xml look like.
Xml1:

```
<session
beginTime="2018-05-11T10:37:30"
halSerialNumber="08J-0735"
testMode="Remote"
userName="name1">
```

Xml2:

```
<session
beginTime="2018-05-11T10:37:30"
halSerialNumber="08J-0735"
testMode="Remote"
userName="name2">
```

I need to combine them but also to connect them with a new node, lets say application.

so my final result want to be

```
    <Application>
<session
    beginTime="2018-05-11T10:37:30"
    halSerialNumber="08J-0735"
    testMode="Remote"
    userName="name1">
</session>
<session
    beginTime="2018-05-11T10:37:30"
    halSerialNumber="08J-0735"
    testMode="Remote"
    userName="name2">
</session>
</Application>
```

Here is what i'm trying to do but it doesnt seems to work.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
         XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
         doc.AppendChild(docNode);

         XmlNode productsNode = doc.CreateElement("Application");
         doc.AppendChild(productsNode);

         XmlNode productNode = doc.CreateElement("Application");


         // Create and add another product node.
         productNode = doc.CreateElement("Application");



        XElement xFileRoot = XElement.Load("C:\\testing\\AN-02-203_2018_05_11_08J-0735_4KW_1_P.xml");
        XElement xFileChild = XElement.Load("C:\\test.xml");
        xFileRoot.Add(xFileChild);

        xFileRoot.Save("C:\\test.xml");
        productsNode.AppendChild(productNode);
```

Here is what i am taking as result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<session beginTime="2018-05-11T10:37:30" halSerialNumber="08J-0735" testMode="Remote" userName="name1">
<session beginTime="2018-05-11T10:37:30" halSerialNumber="08J-0735" testMode="Remote" userName="name2" /> 
</session>
```

Comment: `it doesnt seems to work.` this doesn't tell any thing about the issue you are facing.

Comment: "doesnt seems to work" - please state exactly what isn't working as you expect. Otherwise how do we know what to fix?

Comment: Also, in your code you're creating `products` and `product` elements and there are none of those in what you say is your desired output XML.

Comment: And also you have `xFileRoot` and `xFileChild` but they don't seem to have anything to do with your other elements.

Comment: I change it to application.Is there any other way?

Comment: You still need to tell us what's going wrong.

Comment: I change it to my question

Comment: So does `xFileRoot` load one `session` element, and `xFileChild` load the other one? It would **really** help if you explained which variable did what in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code is very confusing, as it looks like you're dealing with 2 separate XML "things" - one `XmlDocument` and one `XElement`.

If you're OK *just* using XElement you can do this, assuming that `session1` and `session2` are XElement objects holding your input XML:

```
 var application = new XElement("Application");

 var session1 = XElement.Parse("<session\r\nbeginTime=\"2018-05-11T10:37:30\"\r\nhalSerialNumber=\"08J-0735\"\r\ntestMode=\"Remote\"\r\nuserName=\"name1\"/>");
 var session2 = XElement.Parse("<session\r\nbeginTime=\"2018-05-11T10:37:30\"\r\nhalSerialNumber=\"08J-0735\"\r\ntestMode=\"Remote\"\r\nuserName=\"name2\"/>");

 application.Add(session1);
 application.Add(session2);
```

This produces the following output:

```
<Application>
  <session beginTime="2018-05-11T10:37:30" halSerialNumber="08J-0735" testMode="Remote" userName="name1" />
  <session beginTime="2018-05-11T10:37:30" halSerialNumber="08J-0735" testMode="Remote" userName="name2" />
</Application>
```

So, basing this on your code example, you *should* be able to do this:

```
XElement xFileRoot = XElement.Load("C:\\testing\\AN-02-203_2018_05_11_08J-0735_4KW_1_P.xml");
XElement xFileChild = XElement.Load("C:\\test.xml");
var application = new XElement("Application");

application.Add(xFileRoot);
application.Add(xFileChild);
```

Comment: @testsc I don't know what you mean. Read from what XML file? It would help a lot if I knew what the content of each file was when you're loading it in your question code.

Comment: @testsc very glad it helped you!